# Function executed several times while using AddEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm a beginner developer and I'm trying to create a simple soccer website to view standings.
I made the backend logic using Spring, and now I'm trying to develop a frontend page, but I'm struggling implementing a button to edit the data of soccer teams.

Here's the Javascript code:

```
async function getTeamsList() {
    const res = await fetch("/teams");
    const list = await res.json();
    return list;
}

async function writeTeamsList() {
    const teamsList = await getTeamsList();
    let string = "";
    for (let team of teamsList) {
        string += `
        <li class="list-group-item"><img src="${team.icon}"> ${team.name} - 
        <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#delete_team_modal" id="delete_team${team.id}">Elimina</a> / 
        <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#update_team_modal" id="update_team${team.id}">Modifica</a>
        </li>
                `
    }
    document.getElementById("teamlist").innerHTML = string;

    for (let team of teamsList) {
        document.getElementById(`delete_team${team.id}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
            document.getElementById("delete_team_button").addEventListener('click', () => {
                deleteTeam(team.id);
            })
        })
    }
    for (let team of teamsList) {
        document.getElementById(`update_team${team.id}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
            document.getElementById("update_team_name").value = team.name;
            document.getElementById("update_team_icon").value = team.icon;
            document.getElementById("update_team_fail").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("update_team_success").style.display = "none";

            const currentTeamId = team.id;
            document.getElementById("update_team_button").addEventListener('click', () => {
                updateTeam(currentTeamId);
            })
        })
    }
}

async function addTeam() {
    if (document.getElementById("team_name").value != "" && document.getElementById("team_icon").value != "") {
        let team = {
            name: document.getElementById("team_name").value,
            icon: document.getElementById("team_icon").value
        }
        let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
            body: JSON.stringify(team)
        }

        await fetch("/team", options);
        writeTeamsList();
        document.getElementById("team_name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("team_icon").value = "";

        document.getElementById("add_team_fail").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("add_team_success").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("add_team_fail").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("add_team_success").style.display = "none";
    }
}

async function updateTeam(id) {
    if (document.getElementById("update_team_name").value != "" && document.getElementById("update_team_icon").value != "") {
        let team = {
            name: document.getElementById("update_team_name").value,
            icon: document.getElementById("update_team_icon").value
        }
        let options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
            body: JSON.stringify(team)
        }

        await fetch("/update/team/" + id, options);
        writeTeamsList();

        document.getElementById("update_team_name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("update_team_icon").value = "";

        document.getElementById("update_team_fail").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("update_team_success").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("update_team_fail").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("update_team_success").style.display = "none";
    }
}

async function deleteTeam(id) {
    await fetch("/team/" + id, { method: 'DELETE' });
    writeTeamsList();
}

document.getElementById("add_team").addEventListener('click', addTeam);

document.getElementById("add_team_button").addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById("add_team_fail").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("add_team_success").style.display = "none";
})

writeTeamsList();
```

Let's focus on the "writeTeamList" function that I think is the culprit. Here I get a list of all teams, that are printed together with "Elimina" (for deletion), and "Modifica" (for editing) buttons.
What happens is that when I use the "Modifica" button, the AddEventListener calls another AddEventListener that gives to the "update_team_button" the correct "team.id" to update.
The first time it works, and if I update the same team again, it still works. But if I try to update another team after updating a different one before, then all teams are updated with the same data, except for the ones with higher id.

I know it is something related to the use of for loops and AddEventListener inside loops, also nested addEventListener, however it doesn't happens using the "Elimina" button, that shares the same logic.

Do you have some idea on how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance

I tried several ways to implement the AddEventListener and obtain the desired result, however the updateTeam function is still executed several times, editing data that shouldn't be edited.

Comment: Why the `java` tag?

Comment: Java is not Javascript.  Please don't spam tags.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to include the java tag, probably I added it for mistake while trying to add the javascript tag. My apologies...

Comment: You said it all you are adding an event listener in a loop`for (let team of teamsList) { (...) document.getElementById("update_team_button").addEventListener(`. Previous Events are not removed. Make sure to attach the event only one time, and then take only the team id you are looking to edit. As a side note, what you are doing is a bit insecure, as it's possible to inject malicious code via the `.value`, straight to the server. But, no worries, you will fix that later.

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily verbose, and you are making life hard for yourself by working with `id`s. Try looking into relative CSS selectos using the `element.querySelector(<relativeSelector>)` syntax. The `<relativeSelector>` can be something like `"a"` (=the first link element found in `element`) or `"img"` (the first image element found in `element`). You should also use `class` attributes instead of `id`s.

Comment: @NVRM thank you so much for your answer. That's what I was thinking, so I managed to find two solutions. One is to use setAttribute to set an onclick attribute on the button, so every time it is replaced and not added, like the addEventListener behavior. The other solution is to create the button every time with its eventListener, append it to the DOM and then remove it every time an update is completed. However I think that probably there's a better solution, but I'm not able to find it...

Comment: @Carsten Massmann hello, thank you for your answer. I'm still a beginner so certainly I'm not doing thing in the better way... If I use the querySelector, I get a list of all the elements that responds to the relativeSelector, however how can I give the correct team.id and assign it to the updateTeam function? Using an unique id I can select that specific element and give it the specific team.id...

Comment: You are on the good path @Bygepp. We could help much more easily if you do provide a run able snippet. See for example `dataset` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset It's not the only way, ofc, consider working with an object instead, that you create yourself with all infos and ids, so you don't mess with the DOM

Comment: @NVRM again thank you. I think I can provide a snippet, but it can't work without the backend program. Can you suggest me the better way to do it?

Comment: Please, reformulate your question in a more precise way.